# GCM Sends message to an Idle device even with time_to_live is 0

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have the following parameters set on the message:

```
time_to_live = 0;
delay_while_idle = false;
```

Now I send the message to 2 devices : device_1 is kept in idle mode (locked screen)
device_2 is active.

I receive the message on device_2 right away (**Good**, **As Expected**) 
After a while (~ 5 seconds) I unlock the screen of Device_1 and make it active, and to my surprise I also get the message on device_1 (**Strange**, **UnExpected**)

Why is such a behavior, or did I misunderstood the **fact below** in GCM documentation?

**

### Fact from the GCM documentation

** (http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html)
A time_to_live value of 0 seconds. In other words, GCM will guarantee best effort for messages that must be delivered "now or never." **Keep in mind that a time_to_live value of 0 means messages that can't be delivered immediately will be discarded**. However, because such messages are never stored, this provides the best latency for sending notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you send your message with `delay_while_idle = false`, this means it would be delivered to an idle device immediately. You should send it with `delay_while_idle = true`.

Comment: Ok, So whenever (even after 1 hour) I make the device active, I will get to see that message? Or is there any time - limit?

Comment: @UpVert It should be delivered immediately when the device is still idle, so it doesn't matter how long you wait (assuming the device wasn't turned off and was connected to the internet. Otherwise the message can't be delivered).